# Varying Page Lengths

Tags: page-breaking

How can I vary the vertical page length per page?

I want to have the page breaks at essentially arbitrary locations in the document, specified by a command, like `\newpage` but not necessarily this command. Moreover, I want these page breaks to determine the vertical length of the page.

(This must sound crazy!)

Thanks!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Do you mean physical dimensions of the page?  If yes, I had a talk about it at TUG'11.  Our paper is in the upcoming TUGboat, but the talk itself is here:  http://river-valley.zeeba.tv/ebooks-and-paper-size-output-routine-hacking-made-easy/

There are snippets of code on the screen;  if you are interested, let me know, and I put copies of them here.

Update:  here is LaTeX example that shows the idea:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{everyshi,lipsum}
\pagestyle{empty}
\textheight500cm
\EveryShipout{%
  \pdfpageheight=\pagetotal
  \advance\pdfpageheight by 2in
  \advance\pdfpageheight by 2\topmargin
  \advance\pdfpageheight by \textheight
  \advance\pdfpageheight by -\pagegoal}
\begin{document}

\lipsum[3-5]
\pagebreak

This line has a footnote\footnote{\lipsum[6-8]}.
\lipsum[1]

And this line too\footnote{\lipsum[12]}.
\pagebreak

\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes - I do mean the physical dimensions of the page. I'd be very interested in the actual code.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed, thank you! Can this be extended to work with footnotes too?