# Variable page length (1 page per section) with LuaTeX

Tags: luatex, page

If everyone reads a PDF document on screen, and no one actually prints it out, we don't need to break text every 11 inches (or 297 mm) to fit the text into a physical paper. It often creates awkward widow/orphan lines.

So I'm using very long-length paper size to minimize the occurrence of page breaks. But I also thought: If no one prints the document, there is no need to make every page the same size. A reasonable alternative would be to use variable page length so that one page fits exactly the length of one section. This way, there would be no more extra-long white spaces, and readers can use 'next page' command in their PDF reader application to easily jump to next section.

I can do this easily with package `Preview` with `tightpage` option, but it doesn't work with `marginpar`. If there is a marginpar, TeX spits out "Float(s) lost" error.

Package `Standalone` also does this, but it loads package `Preview` with `tightpage` option internally to do this, so it's no different. Marginpar still doesn't work.

I also had a look on this answer ([Varying Page Lengths](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35847/varying-page-lengths)). This works perfectly with marginpar, But the code is (presumably) for PDFTeX only. It doesn't work with LuaLaTeX. Maybe I can modify the code a little to make it work with Lua, but I don't know how.

Minimally non-working example with `Preview` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\renewcommand{\PreviewBorder}{1cm}
\newcommand{\Newpage}{\end{preview}\begin{preview}}

\begin{document}
\begin{preview}
Some text to test.\marginpar{Some text in marginpar}
\end{preview}
\end{document}
```

Comment: With the `preview` package you also need the `luatex85` package.

Comment: Thanks for reply. But adding `\usepackage{luatex85}` to the MWE above didn't change anything.

Comment: Use `\RequirePackage{luatex85}` before `\documentclass` in [Boris' answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/35848/10995).  Your example won't typeset regardless (also with `pdflatex`) as the `preview` package cannot do marginpar.

Answer (score 0):

Some pdfTeX commands have been promoted to LuaTeX primitives, and `\pdfpageheight` is among them (see [the documentation of luatex85](https://www.texlive.info/CTAN/macros/generic/luatex85/luatex85.pdf)). To achieve the effect of [Boris' answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/35848/18816) in LuaTeX, you simply change `\pdfpageheight` to `\pageheight`. For completeness, I copy Boris' code with the above-mentioned modification:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{everyshi,lipsum}
\pagestyle{empty}
\textheight500cm
\EveryShipout{%
  \pageheight=\pagetotal
  \advance\pageheight by 2in
  \advance\pageheight by 2\topmargin
  \advance\pageheight by \textheight
  \advance\pageheight by -\pagegoal}
\begin{document}

\lipsum[3-5]
\pagebreak

This line has a footnote\footnote{\lipsum[6-8]}.
\lipsum[1]

And this line too\footnote{\lipsum[12]}.
\pagebreak

\end{document}
```