# Varying page lengths with lualatex and memoir

Tags: luatex, memoir, paper-size

I'd like to do exactly this

[Varying Page Lengths](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35847/varying-page-lengths/35848?newreg=cf7b39ba69b54e9fb51cffb807ab885c)

> How can I vary the vertical page length per page?
>
> I want to have the page breaks at essentially >arbitrary locations in the document, specified by >a command, like `\newpage` but not necessarily this >command. Moreover, I want these page breaks to >determine the vertical length of the page.

but with memoir and lualatex. I attempted to implement this

[Variable page length (1 page per section) with LuaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/408250/variable-page-length-1-page-per-section-with-luatex?noredirect=1&lq=1)

by using

`\documentclass[class=memoir]{standalone}`

but it did not work.

I have been able to make one very long page. This is what I have so far.

```
\documentclass[12pt,extrafontsizes,oneside,final]{memoir}%
\setstocksize{500cm}{22cm}%
\settrimmedsize{\stockheight}{\stockwidth}{*}% 
\setlrmarginsandblock{40mm}{40mm}{*}%
\setulmarginsandblock{28mm}{20mm}{*}%
\checkandfixthelayout%
%
\input{Options/preamble}%
%
\begin{document}%
\include{Bodies/BodyV2}%
\end{document}%
```

Comment: You have not shown us what you have done. What is in `Options/preamble`? What is in `Bodies/BodyV2`? How do you expect to be helped if nobody has any idea what you have tried? --- GOM

Comment: I havent actually tried anything. I didn't think those mattered because in preamble there are just my packages which don't have to do with papersize, and in BodyV2 is the document. All I've done with layout is there.

Comment: You say "BodyV2 is the document. All I've done with layout is there." BUT you have not deigned to show us any of the contents of `BodyV2`. Re-reading it seems that you have not tried anything at all. On this site it is desirable for questioners to have tried and show the code that does not work as they expect. Perhaps you should rewrite your question. --- GOM

Comment: Oh I meant all I've done with the layout has been posted.

I did say I tried the standalone class with the `class=memoir` option. I'll add more that I tried.