# fancyhdr with variable page height

Tags: header-footer, page-breaking, fancyhdr

I want the page height to be adjusted by the contents. I find [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/35848/54169) works. However, I also want to use `fancyhdr` to modify the header.

Here is the MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{everyshi,lipsum}
\textheight500cm
\EveryShipout{%
  \pdfpageheight=\pagetotal
  \advance\pdfpageheight by 2in
  \advance\pdfpageheight by 2\topmargin
  \advance\pdfpageheight by \textheight
  \advance\pdfpageheight by -\pagegoal}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\makeatletter
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[C]{}
\fancyfoot[L]{\ttfamily\@title}
\fancyfoot[R]{\ttfamily\@author}
\makeatother

\title{This is Title}
\author{Name}

\begin{document}
\lipsum

\end{document}
```

As you can see, the header didn't show up, only a header rule is there.

**Question**: how to make `fancyhdr` work with variable page height?

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/268692/fancyhdr-resets-geometry-to-adjust-header-heights/268720?r=SearchResults&s=1%7C46.6028#268720 although I would use \AddToHooks now instead of everypage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The page dimensions are changed at shipout, so [`fancyhdr`](//ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr) places them off the visual page (`500cm` or 50m into nothingness). You can raise them into position though:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{everyshi,lipsum}

\textheight500cm
\EveryShipout{%
  \pdfpageheight=\pagetotal
  \advance\pdfpageheight by 2in
  \advance\pdfpageheight by 2\topmargin
  \advance\pdfpageheight by \textheight
  \advance\pdfpageheight by -\pagegoal}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\makeatletter
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[C]{}
\fancyfoot[L]{\raisebox{\dimexpr\textheight-\pagetotal}[0pt][0pt]{\ttfamily\@title}}
\fancyfoot[R]{\raisebox{\dimexpr\textheight-\pagetotal}[0pt][0pt]{\ttfamily\@author}}
\makeatother

\title{This is Title}
\author{Name}

\begin{document}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

You may have to play around with the value it's raised by to get your position correct. An alternative is to place the content without `fancyhdr`, either as part of the text, or as part of the shipout routine.

Comment: May I ask how to place the header as part of the shipout ourtine?

Comment: @Gau-Syu: For a basic header, you can just add it to `\fancyhead` (as in, `\fancyhead[C]{This is a header}`. This works since you're technically only changing the bottom of the page (the page height/length), not the top, so headers would work as expected. Does this work for you?